# Integrating the geometric series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, proof-explanation

We Know ($ z \in \textbf{C} $):

$\dfrac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{k} z^{n} + \dfrac{z^{k+1}}{1-z}$

Integrating this along the straight line $L$ from $0$ to $z$:

$ -ln(1-z) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}\dfrac{z^{n+1}}{n+1} + \int_{L}\dfrac{w^{k+1}}{1-w} dw$

If $ \vert z \vert < 1$, an upper bound for the absolute value of the integral is:

$ \vert  \int_{L} \dfrac{w^{k+1}}{1-w} dw \vert \leq \vert z \vert \dfrac{\vert z \vert^{k+1}}{1 - \vert  z \vert} = \dfrac{\vert z \vert^{k+2}}{1-\vert z \vert}$

From here we get:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^{n}}{n} = - ln(1-z)$, $ \quad \vert z \vert<1  $.

Can someone tell me how the upper bound was found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the real case:

If $0 < z < 1$,
then
there are two different upper bounds.

$\begin{array}\\
\left|\int_{0}^z\dfrac{w^{k+1}}{1-w} dw\right|
&\le \left|\int_{0}^z\dfrac{w^{k+1}}{1-z} dw\right|
\qquad z \ge w \implies 1-z \le 1-w\\
&=\dfrac1{1-z} \left|\int_{0}^zw^{k+1} dw\right|\\
&=\dfrac1{1-z} \left|\dfrac{z^{k+2}}{(k+2)}\right|\\
&=\dfrac{z^{k+2}}{(1-z)(k+2)}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\left|\int_{0}^z\dfrac{w^{k+1}}{1-w} dw\right|
&\le \left|\int_{0}^z\dfrac{z^{k+1}}{1-w} dw\right|
\qquad z \ge w\\
&= z^{k+1}\int_{0}^z\dfrac{1}{1-w} dw\\
&= z^{k+1}\int_{1-z}^1\dfrac{1}{w} dw\\
&= z^{k+1}(\ln(w))|_{1-z}^1\\
&= z^{k+1}(-\ln(1-z))\\
\end{array}
$

and then use
whatever bounds you want
based on
$-\ln(1-z)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^k}{k}
$.